# Haskell counted list type

Tags: haskell, list, existential-type

So, just for fun, I've been playing with a CountedList type in Haskell, using Peano numbers
and [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors).

Type-safe `head` and `tail` just seem really cool to me.

And I think I've reached the limit of what I know how to do

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
module CountedList (
  Zero, Succ, CountedList,
  toList, ofList, 
  empty, cons, uncons, 
  head, tail, 
  fmap, map, foldl, foldr, filter
) where

import qualified List (foldr, foldl, filter)
import Prelude hiding (map, head, foldl, foldr, tail, filter)

data Zero
data Succ n
data CountedList n a = CL [a]

toList :: CountedList n a -> [a]
toList (CL as) = as

ofList :: [a] -> CountedList n a
ofList [] = empty
ofList (a:as) = cons a $ ofList as

empty :: CountedList Zero a
empty = CL []

cons :: a -> CountedList n a -> CountedList (Succ n) a
cons a = CL . (a:) . toList

uncons :: CountedList (Succ n) a -> (a, CountedList n a)
uncons (CL (a:as)) = (a, CL as)

head :: CountedList (Succ n) a -> a
head = fst . uncons

tail :: CountedList (Succ n) a -> CountedList n a
tail = snd . uncons

instance Functor (CountedList n) where
  fmap f = CL . fmap f . toList

map :: (a -> b) -> CountedList n a -> CountedList n b
map = fmap

foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> CountedList n b -> a
foldl f a = List.foldl f a . toList

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> CountedList n a -> b
foldr f b = List.foldr f b . toList

filter :: (a -> Bool) -> CountedList n a -> CountedList m a
filter p = ofList . List.filter p . toList
```

(sorry for any transcription errors - the machine I originally wrote this on w/ my Haskell compiler is currently down).

Most of what I've done compiles w/o an issue, but I run into issues with `ofList` and `filter`.  I think I understand why - when I say `ofList :: [a] -> CountedList n a`, I'm saying `ofList :: forall n . [a] -> CountedList n a` - that the list created can be of any desired count type.  What I want to write is the equivalent of the pseudo type `ofList :: exists n . [a] -> CountedList n a`, but I don't know how.

Is there a workaround that would let me write `ofList` and `filter` functions like I'm imagining, or have I reached the limit of what I can do with this?  I have a sense that there's some trick with [existential types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_types) that I'm missing.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would downvote this question. I upvoted for balance.

Comment: Looks like someone clicked the downvote by mistake and fixed it: there's no downvote currently.

Comment: Indeed, I clicked the wrong button on my phone and then lost the network connection. I hope Stack Overflow will get a mobile stylesheet (with some bigger arrows) in the near future :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't write

```
ofList :: [a] -> (exists n. CountedList n a)  -- wrong
```

but you can write

```
withCountedList :: [a] -> (forall n. CountedList n a -> b) -> b
```

and pass it a function which represents what you would have done with the result of `ofList`, as long as its type is independent of the length of the list.

By the way, you can ensure the invariant that the type of a list corresponds to its length in the type system, and not rely on smart constructors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data CountedList n a where
    Empty :: CountedList Zero a
    Cons :: a -> CountedList n a -> CountedList (Succ n) a
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards [GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADT#Example_with_lists), that's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define `ofList` or `filter` this way because they are confounding type-level checks with run-time values. In particular, in the type of the result, `CountedList n a`, the type `n` must be determined at compile time. The implied desire is that `n` should be commensurate with the length of the list that is the first argument. But that clearly can't be known until run-time.

Now, it might be possible to define a typeclass, say Counted, and then (with the appropriate Haskell extension), define these like:

```
ofList :: [a] -> (forall n. (CountedListable CountedList n) => CountedList n a)
```

But you'd have a hard time doing anything with such a result, since the only operations that `CountedListable` could support would be extracting the count. You couldn't, say get the `head` of such a value because head couldn't be defined for all instances of `CountedListable`